# Code only works when I place a breakpoint

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I got the following code (in a seperate file called page.js):

```
var page = new function() {

    this.getImdbID = function(){
        var imdbid = '';
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
                 imdbid='0944835';
            }); 
            return imdbid;
    };
}
```

Which gets called by the following code (which is in background.html).

```
var imdbid = page.getImdbID();
```

This code only works when I place a breakpoint on the "return imdbid;" row. When I skip the breakpoint it only returns an empty string. Is there anything I have missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that it works when you place a breakpoint suggests a timing issue.

In this case, I would suppose that `getSelected` is an asynchronous operation (hence why it takes a callback), and so you would need to wait for it to complete and the callback to be executed before the variable has the value you want.

Comment: This is correct. imdbid gets assigned in the callback, which may not be called until after the return statement is executed.

Comment: ah that makes sense. I will have to find another way then. Thanks for clearing that up for me.